# ionic grid cannot render in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

i want to display the images from the JSON file in the firebase database ,only the sliderimage is showing but not the product images. please help me

```
<ion-content  class="dark">
    <ion-slides *ngIf="promoImagesLoaded" autoplay=6000  slidesPerView=1>
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let promo of promoSliders">
            <img src="{{promo.name}}" alt="">
          </ion-slide>  

    </ion-slides>


     <ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let i of productRows">
        <ion-col *ngFor="let product of products | slice:(i*2):(i+1)*2" width-50 (click)="showDetails(product)">
          <ion-card>         
            <img src="{{product.thumb}}" alt="">
            <ion-card-content>
                <p>
                    {{product.price | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}
                </p>
            </ion-card-content>
           </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Any error in console? and what does `productRows` contains?

Comment: loadProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts();
    this.events.subscribe('productsLoaded', () => {
      this.products = this.productService.products;
      this.productRows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.products.length/2)).keys())
       
    })
  }

Comment: its part of the loadProducts() method

Comment: no errors in the console the ionic grid is supposed to be display below the image slider  , <ion-slider> works perfect i can see the images on the console